# Unable to insert video into the watch later (WL) playlist

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Google Apps script that's been running for a while without error.

It takes new RSS feed items from my RSS provider, gets some basic information about the video from YoutTbe and then adds the video to a certain playlist based on that.

Since a couple of days ago, while the rest of the playlists are working fine, adding any video to the WL (watch later) playlist results in the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlistItems.insert failed with error: The API does not support the ability to insert videos into the specified playlist.

This is the request I am sending (again, working for two other playlists created by me):

```
{
    snippet: {
        playlistId: 'WL',
        resourceId: {
            videoId: '<videoId>',
            kind: 'youtube#video'
        }
    }
}
```

and it's being used like this:

```
YouTube.PlaylistItems.insert(resource, "snippet");
```

Additionally, I do log the contents of the WL playlist in the beginning of the script and the playlist items comes back as an empty list (although the list has videos in it). As far as I can tell, those two issues started at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [entry from September 9, 2020](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#september-9,-2020) of the official revision history of the YouTube Data API, the watch later playlist is deprecated w.r.t to using it with the [`PlaylistItems.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert) API endpoint:

> [...] The `playlistItems.insert` method's and `playlistItems.delete` method's support for these playlists are also now fully deprecated [...]

The [entry from January 28, 2021](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history#january-28,-2021) states that:

> [...] While users' watch history and watch later lists are, indeed, not accessible via the API [...]

Therefore, you'll have to acknowledge that your use case of `PlaylistItems.insert` endpoint works no more.

That's unfortunate, but a (documented) fact.

Comment: Classic google, exclude a single use case and don't have a note about it in the API doc itself but require the user to go over the revision history.

You only know that watch later is excluded from the API if you go to playlistItems.list and see the (now deprecated) error in the error list, wonderful.

Comment: I'll add that -- even though it proves to be useful at times --, the revision history is by no means (that's unfortunate!) sound and complete. That's to say that, while being official, is not fully authoritative. One has to rely on several sources of info when dealing with this API. (Another such source: Google's [own issue tracker site](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:186600).)

Comment: I can tell there are some war stories behind that comment. Stay vigilant

Comment: Tried to make a jokey comment, everything is fine

Comment: I meant what I wrote; that's based on my experience with this API. Just being a bit confused by your suggestion. If, as a programmer, one is inclined to consider that revision history a sort of (public) *ChangeLog*, then he/she will (again, unfortunately) be very disappointed. I'm not saying that that page has no merits on its own; only that it's not a *public ChangeLog*.